# ffmpeg seems to be capping my output

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract individual frames from a video.

```
ffmpeg -i face_source.wmv face_sourceframes/image%03d.jpg
```

is almost working just fine. The first six or so appear perfect (have roughly 30kB file size), but then they continuously degrade (e.g. 23kB, 17kB, etc.) until all frames are 11kB. Of course, these frames are pixelated and not desired.

I tried forcing a bitrate with the `-b` option. ffmpeg tells me this about the inupt video:

```
  Duration: 00:00:10.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 781 kb/s
```

So I set bitrate, first using `-b 781k`, and then, just to be safe, also tried doubling it, to `-b 1562k`. Neither of these options made any apparent difference in the output.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I also tried extraction from an mpeg version of the video, exact same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the quantizer with the `-qscale` option using a value between 1-31: 1 is best quality and 31 is worst.

That should help if it indeed is trying to do some rate control.

However, it could be that your input video is itself of bad quality? Try playing it and checking. I suspect that is the case.

Comment: the pixelation does not occur in the video. should i set the quantizer high or low? i'll go play around and report back!

Comment: UPDATE: setting `-qscale 1` makes it run perfectly! Thank you for your help. Can you go into a little more detail on what this option does? It works, but what was my issue, and how does this option solve it?

Comment: Qscale is the quanitzer. By default ffmpeg tries to achieve a target bitrate. So qscale tells it to ignore bitrate and instead use a fixed quantizer value.